# Mezzanine HOST_THEMES www- subdomain pointing to wrong site

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm using the Mezzanine Django-based CMS using its Multi-Tenancy ability to serve two sites through the same backend, and have a quirk occurring with respect to the "www" subdomain from one of the sites. At the moment, this is how it's working:

```
site_1.com   ->   site_1
www.site_1.com -> site_1
site_2.com   ->   site_2
www.site_2.com -> site_1
```

As you can see, the "www" subdomain is going to the wrong site. The HOST_THEMES setting seems to be set correctly, however - like so:

```
HOST_THEMES = [('www.site_1.com', 'site_1_theme'),
                ('site_1.com', 'site_1_theme'),
                ('www.site_2.com', 'site_2_theme'),
                ('site_2.com', 'site_2_theme')]
```

Additionally, Admin>Settings>Sites is set like so:

```
site_1.com
site_2.com
```

(No "www"s are listed, since adding one would add a completely separate site in the admin for content). What is the proper way to handle www subdomains here? Why would it properly handle the raw domain, yet not the www?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the www sites to the non-www sites (or vice-versa), in your nginx/apache conf.